# ElementListUnion - Simple xml giving duplicate annotation for generic list objects

Tags: android, generics, deserialization, unmarshalling, simple-framework

I am trying to deserialize a List field using elementlistunion

```
Customer.java

 @ElementListUnion({ @ElementList(inline = false, type = Thing.class),
        @ElementList(inline = false, type = AnotherThing.class) })
List<Object> things = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

where Thing and AnotherThing are 2 POJO's.But Iam getting the following exception

```
03-21 18:56:31.940: E/AndroidRuntime(2289): Caused by:
org.simpleframework.xml.core.PersistenceException: Duplicate annotation
of name 'things' on
@org.simpleframework.xml.ElementListUnion(value=
[@org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList(data=false,
 empty=true, entry=, inline=false, name=, required=true, type=class
 com.data.Thing), @org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList(data=false,
 empty=true, entry=, inline=false, name=, required=true, type=class
 com.data.AnotherThing)]) on field 'things' java.util.List
 com.data.Customer.things
```

I have been stuck on this for a whole day now. Please Help.

Here is my response xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customer>
  <address>
     <no>122</no>
      <street>xxx</street>
  </address>
  <id>122</id>
  <name>James Bond</name>
  <things>
      <thing>
        <val>185</val>
      </thing>
      <thing>
        <val>162</val>
      </thing>
   </things>
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <customer> <address>
  <no>122</no>
  <street>chennai</street>
 </address>
 <anotherthings />
 <id>122</id>
 <name>James Bond</name>
 <things>
  <thing>
   <val>185</val>
  </thing>
  <thing>
   <val>162</val>
  </thing>
 </things>
</customer>

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple XML ElementListUnion - two generic lists not allowed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15533272/simple-xml-elementlistunion-two-generic-lists-not-allowed)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why are you trying to make two classes in ElementsListUnion. You can use

```
@ElementList(inline = false, type = Thing.class)
```

instead of this or

```
 @ElementListUnion({ @ElementList(inline = false, type = Thing.class, required = false),
        @ElementList(inline = false, type = AnotherThing.class, required = false) })
```

if you don't send two elements types every time.